# Sum of values when end of range is defined by Cell("address")

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum the total value preceding a lookup value in a range with a defined starting point. can anyone clue me into why this formula wont work?

```
=SUM(E9:CELL("address",INDEX(E9:BN9,MATCH("130LSR",E9:BN9,0))))
```

The result from just the cell function works:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(E9:BN9,MATCH("130LSR",E9:BN9,0)))
```

This returns $F$9 in my sheet which is correct. It also has the workbook and sheet references prior, is that my problem? is there a way to remove the book and sheet references? The sum function obviously works if I provide the address, but why can't i define the end of my range with the cell(address) formula?

Comment: Why don't you just use the INDEX/MATCH and drop trying to use the CELL part entirely?

Comment: ^^^^ just need: `=SUM(E9:INDEX(E9:BN9,MATCH("130LSR",E9:BN9,0)))`